# I'm looking for this gothic / blackletter font (or a very similar one)

Tags: font-identification

I would like to know what font this is, or the name of a similar font.

I've already tried with font from an image recognition services and also sites with step by step font identification. It's not a typical serif or sans-serif font, so no luck so far.

[image]
[image]

I've decided that it's easier to use one of the similar fonts and to customize it for the final result.

Thanks everybody for your help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. I've already tried Automated or semi-automated options (web sites that provide font recognition from an image) and no luck. I will also try some other forums to get the answer. Thanks

Comment: I am sure someone here will come up with the solution, but it would be really good if you edited your question and let us know what resources you have tried with no luck.

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting one! Where did you find this guy from? Did you scan it in? The rough edges on the 'o' glyphs look slightly different; I was curious if that was because of scanning or if it was OpenType alternative glyphs.

Comment: Actually, it was printed on a lighter, my client took a picture with a camera and I've just edited curves for better readability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couldn't find the correct font but this is the most similar I could find on dafont.com

http://www.dafont.com/augusta.font?text=Book

[image]

You're best looking through the [Gothic](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=401&page=6&text=Book) section on dafont

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I really appreciate it. I'm also looking manually (going from site to site and checking each similar font)

Comment: @gilezajner Also look for `blackletter` fonts, and on sites that use tags, try `medieval`

Answer (score 5):

It's possible that the 'B' character was customized by the original designer, especially if this is from a logo. During your research you might want to focus on the 'o' and 'k' characters to find the most similar font and then go from there.

Comment: you're 100% right

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware of Augusta, however it looks useful to add another letter B, partly similar to the B in question.

The name of the font is [Silver Bullet FF](http://www.blambot.com/font_silverbullet.shtml), and it was probably influenced by alphabet by A.Durer.

other letters does not resemble the font in question.

[image]

[image]